# Hide 'Upload' field in Redux Framework

Tags: jquery, upload, hide, redux, redux-framework

I want to hide the 'Upload' field in Redux Framework.

I've found a way, but it can't hide the 'Upload' field. I've tried with 'image' => false, but it doesn't work.

```
'show'  => array(
    'title' => true,
    'description' => true,
    'url' => false
),
```

[Hide 'Upload' field in Redux Framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfWLk.png)

Has any suggestion or comment? Or, how to I can do it by editing the core file?

Thanks.

Comment: Please see the image- http://i.stack.imgur.com/YfWLk.png

Answer (score 1):

Solved :)

How to?

Add a class name.

```
array(
    'title'     =>  __('Add Service Item', 'polos'),
    'id'        =>  'service_items',
    'class'     =>  'serviceExClass', // See theme functions.php
    'type'      =>  'slides',
    'Placeholder'   =>  array (
        'url'       =>  'Service Icon Code',
        'title'     =>  'Service Title',
        'description'       =>  'Service Description',
    )
)
```

I've define the class name serviceExClass. Now go to theme functions.php file and write there-

```
function my_custom_admin_head_ar() {
    echo '<style>
    .serviceExClass .redux-container-slides .redux_slides_add_remove {
        display: none !important;
    }
    </style>';
    }
add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_custom_admin_head_ar' );
```

Now the 'Upload' field will be hidden for the specific section. My friend helped me lot, to find out the solution.

Thanks.